# Does MPI_finalize release memory?

Tags: fortran, mpi

In the following code, I have an array **b** which is being used in MPI. As far as I understand, each processor gets a copy of **b** even before the call to `MPI_INIT`. But what happens after we call `MPI_FINALIZE`? Is that piece of memory still available to each processor?

In a similar manner, what would happen if **b** is instead declared as a pointer, it is allocated inside `MPI_INIT`-`MPI_FINALIZE` but it is not deallocated? Is that memory still available after finalizing MPI?

```
program main
use mpi
implicit none

integer myr, numpr, ier
integer b(1000)

call MPI_INIT(ier)
call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, myr, ier)
call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, numpr, ier)

if (myr .eq. 0) then
   !initialize b array
endif 

call MPI_BCAST(b, 100, MPI_INTEGER, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ier)

call MPI_FINALIZE(ier)

!do more calculations with b

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you imagine the code that you've written without any of the MPI stuff, you'll see that each processor starts with a B array of size 1000, because you declare it as such:

```
integer b(1000)
```

Neither MPI_Init nor MPI_Finalise are involved in allocating or deallocating any of this memory.

Likewise, you can allocate an array at run time (C) and it will stick around until you explicitly deallocate it:

```
PROGRAM main
use mpi
implicit none

integer myr, numpr, ier
integer b(1000)
INTEGER, ALLOCATABLE :: C(:)



call MPI_INIT(ier)
call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD, myr, ier)
call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, numpr, ier)

ALLOCATE(C(1000))

if (myr .eq. 0) then
  b = 100  ! Set all values to 100
  c = 99   ! Ditto 99
endif 

call MPI_BCAST(b, 1000, MPI_INTEGER, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ier)
call MPI_BCAST(c, 1000, MPI_INTEGER, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ier)

call MPI_FINALIZE(ier)

PRINT *, myr, B(200)
PRINT *, myr, C(200)


DEALLOCATE(C)

END PROGRAM main
```

produces output:

```
           1         100
           1          99
           0         100
           0          99
```

Also, note that you had a typo (I think) in your initial code. You only send the first 100 members of B (which has size 1000).

Comment: Yeah if you want to. You might want to explicitly state MPI_BCAST(B(1:100), 100, ...  just to be on the safe side